# Finding out if a URL param exists in JS-ASP

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, jscript

I am editing other people's code, written in server-side JS for ASP, and have run into a problem that probably has a very simple solution.

I'm outputting some code from a URL param like this:

```
<%=Request.QueryString("param")%>
```

The problem is that if the param doesn't exist, I need to do something else. So I tried:

```
<% 
  var param = Request.QueryString("param");
  if (!param) { param = "Some Default Value"; }
%>
<%=param%>
```

The problem is that the `if` never seems to evaluate to `true`, even when the URL param is missing. I'm guessing that the `!image` condition doesn't work here. What should my test condition be?

(Please forgo stern warnings about doing escaping of URL params to prevent XSS.)

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to check whether a query string parameter exists is with the `Count` property:

```
<% 
  var param = Request.QueryString("param");
  if (param.Count === 0) { param = "Some Default Value"; }
%>
<%=param%>
```

According to the documentation for [`Request.QueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx),

> The value of Request.QueryString(*parameter*) is an array of all of the
>   values of parameter that occur in QUERY_STRING.

That's probably why the simple `if (!param)` check doesn't work.

Comment: This works nicely if you want to detect whether the parameter is present, but not if the parameter is empty.  For example, the URL `http://example.com?foo=` will return a count of 1, not 0.  Cheeso's answer below works better if you need to test for an empty value.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do.

```
function qs(name) {
    var v = Request.QueryString(name),
        v2 = "x" + v + "x";
    if ((v2=="xundefinedx") && (v != "undefined")) {
        return null;
    }
    return v + ''; // force string
}
```

Comment: A slightly simpler form of this using Cheran's answer would be: `if (param.count == 0 || param + '' == '') param = 'some default value';`

Answer (score -1):

In JSP you have to use `getParameter` instead of `QueryString`

The code in JSP would be

```
<% 
  String param = request.getParameter("param");
  if (param.length() == 0) { param = "Some Default Value"; }
%>
```

Comment: I'm not using JSP. This is for an ASP site with pages written in Javascript instead of VBScript.